# Error in knitting rmd file to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I can't knit my rmd document because of this error:

```
title: "R two"
author: "Minoo "
date: "Monday, February 13, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
```

processing file: R_two.Rmd

```
  |...                                                              |   4%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....                                                            |   8%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |........                                                         |  12%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........                                                      |  17%
label: unnamed-chunk-2
  |..............                                                   |  21%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................                                                 |  25%
label: unnamed-chunk-3
  |...................                                              |  29%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................                                           |  33%
label: unnamed-chunk-4
  |........................                                         |  38%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................                                      |  42%
label: unnamed-chunk-5
  |..............................                                   |  46%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................................                                 |  50%
label: unnamed-chunk-6
  |...................................                              |  54%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................................                           |  58%
label: unnamed-chunk-7
  |.........................................                        |  62%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-8
  |..............................................                   |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................                |  75%
label: unnamed-chunk-9
  |...................................................              |  79%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................................................           |  83%
label: unnamed-chunk-10
  |.........................................................        |  88%
  ordinary text without R code

  |............................................................     |  92%
label: unnamed-chunk-11
```

> Error in shell.exe(url) : '.report/report.html' not found calls:
>   ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> browseURL -> shell.exec
>   Excution halted

Any idea to fix it? 
I use R-3.3.2 version and RStudio-1.0.136 version.

Comment: Can you post your script or at least the YAML associated with it rather than your processing output?

Comment: My script is really large and I couldn't post it, I couldn't understand your mean by YAML? @be_green

Comment: @minoo the YAML is what comes before the rmd tipically something like: `---
title: "Metanalysis"
author: "Derek Corcoran"
date: "February 13, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---`

Comment: @DerekCorcoran thanks, as I understood your mean, I edit my post.

Comment: I think if you have just the .html or just the PDF it might work....but the idea of default means you cannot have two defaults. If you need both, run them one at a time!

Answer (score 0):

Edit it this way and it should work

```
title: "R two"
author: "Minoo "
date: "Monday, February 13, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my code again, in rmd format I could not find any kind of error and this error happened when I wanted to convert it to pdf or HTML format. In a part of my code I had this
library("ReportingTools")

```
htmlRep <- HTMLReport(shortName="report", title="My report",
                      reportDirectory="./report")
publish(resOrderedDF, htmlRep)
url <- finish(htmlRep)
browseURL(url)
```

So, by this code, it needed to open a page in a browser. I removed this line

```
browseURL(url)
```

of the code and tried to convert the rmd file again, and this time it did not happen.